# how to set base directory for ONLY concat task in grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm registering my grunt tasks this way,

```
grunt.registerTask('scripts',['clean','concat']);
```

I'd like to set a common source directory for the `concat` task only,

and I can't use `grunt.file.setBase` because it changes the source directory for both the tasks.

Can i set this somehow inside grunt?

Comment: where is the problem only configuring the concat-config?

Answer (score 1):

just put a config in your concat task file:

`grunt.config('concat.scripts', {
  options: {
    separator: ';'
  },
  dest: 'dest_dir/file.js',
  src: files_list_or_directory,
});`